# Need to replace everything after the second match

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok so if I have this pattern:

```
ab&bc&cd&de&ef
```

And I need to replace all the ampersands except for the first one with commas so it ends up looking like this:

```
ab&bc,cd,de,ef
```

Its probably very simple but for the life of me I can't get this one figured out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that easy because JavaScript doesn't do lookbehind.

Try

```
result = subject.replace(/(^(?:[^&]+&[^&]+)|[^&]+)&/g, "$1,");
```

Explanation:

`(` Capture the following into backreference `$1`:

`^(?:[^&]+&[^&]+)` Start-of-string, followed by two fields separated by an ampersand

`|` or

`[^&]+` one field (a field being one or more non-ampersand characters).

`)` End of capturing group

`&` match an ampersand.

That way, the first ampersand will be skipped in the match. If you need to handle empty fields, then use

```
(^(?:[^&]*&[^&]*)|[^&]*)&
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not split the original string on `&`

Join `piece1`, `piece2`, ....`pieceN` with `,`

Join `piece0` with the result of above with `&`

Comment: Its not up to me. Has to be regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^&]{2}&([^&]{2}&)*
```

Can't help you with the javascript part, but maybe that'll help?